# Get Facebook user ID in FB PHP SDK 4.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

In FB SDK 3.0, you could run `$facebook->getUser()` to get the user's Facebook UID.

SDK 4.0 doesn't have a BaseFacebook object any more; I can't see how to get the user ID off of a FacebookSession created by FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper. How do you do it?

Comment: Please file issues at the github bug tracker (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/issues) otherwise we will never know about it

Comment: I didn't even consider the possibility that this was a bug; I just assumed I was missing something in the documentation. I guess I'll go file a bug now...

Comment: If it isn't a bug I assume they will just close it and tell you what to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you already have an active session or an access token, you can do the following to get the user_id:

```
// set session from cookie or via helper
$session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );
$user_id = $session->getSessionInfo()->asArray()['user_id']
echo $user_id
```

See [this tutorial](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/05/01/facebook-api-php-sdk-updated-to-v4-0-0/) for information on using a session saved in a cookie or creating a new session. It's a long solution but this the easiest way to retrieve the user_id using the new SDK. It's advisable to save it in a session for easier retrieval.

Comment: 401 authorization required.

Answer (score 2):

As of PHP SDK v4.0.3 there's no way to get the user ID without doing a network request. This is unfortunate because [the signed request already contains the user_id](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/), so it seems silly to do a network request just for that one piece of data.

But, if you're willing to do the network request, `$session->getSessionInfo()->getId()` will retrieve the full session info from `/debug_token`, including the user ID.

You might prefer to do a FacebookRequest for `/me`, which will provide the user ID and the user's profile info. (But it's more typing.)

```
$me = (new FacebookRequest(
  $session, 'GET', '/me'
))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
echo $me->getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Facebook SDK 4.0.9.
I needed to get the user id when making AJAX calls and my setup is as follows:

- when constructing fb sdk wrapper, call `FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(<ID>, <SECRET>`
- defined a function `get_user_id` as follows:

  ```
  public function get_user_id() {
      $sr = new SignedRequest((new FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper())->getRawSignedRequestFromCookie());
      return $sr->getUserId();
  }
  ```

`getRawSignedRequestFromCookie` is defined here https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/master/src/Facebook/Helpers/FacebookSignedRequestFromInputHelper.php#L159-L165

I chose `FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper` for convenience, but I think you can opt for any (I guess): https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/tree/master/src/Facebook/Helpers

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an active session called '$session' then you just use:

```
$session->getUserId();
```

In my code I log on with Javascript SDK, then in PHP:

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($api_key, $api_secret);
$helper = new FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper();
try {
    $session = $helper->getSession();
    $output = $session->getUserId();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
    $output = '-1';
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    $output = '-2';
}
```

Comment: `$session->getUserId();` will return null even when `$session` is valid